# Проблема при клонировании проекта flutter app

Tags: android-studio, github, flutter

Подскажите, как правильно в Android Studio клонировать проект flutter app из репозитория GitHub? При обычной процедуре клонирования создается ущербный проект android, без main.dart

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался самостоятельно:

1) Идем в меню VCS и выбираем пункт Checkout from version control...

2) Загружаем проект из репозитория GitHub и НЕ СОЗДАЕМ НОВЫЙ ПРОЕКТ Android Studio

3) Идем в меню File и открываем существующий проект

4) Студия ругается, что Flutter SDK не сконфигурирован, делаем это

5) Потом делаем Get dependencies (тоже есть предупреждение об этом)